# C++ how can I add a linux user to a group programatically

Tags: c++, linux

is it possible to add a user on Linux to a group, programatically when I start my program? I am using C++. I know it can be done with the shell, but I need to do it in my C++ program, however I don't know what to use.

Comment: Since you're using Linux, most user-space tools are open-source, with the source available, like for example the `adduser` command-line tool. You could find out which package it came from and check the source how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is solved by many configuration management software. [For example in Salt:](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/274464a85bcfbf96dc06caa58cfae432d066db32/salt/modules/groupadd.py#L136)

```
def adduser(name, username):
    on_redhat_5 = __grains__.get('os_family') == 'RedHat' and __grains__.get('osmajorrelease') == '5'    
    if __grains__['kernel'] == 'Linux':
        if on_redhat_5:
            cmd = 'gpasswd -a {0} {1}'.format(username, name)
        else:
            cmd = 'gpasswd --add {0} {1}'.format(username, name)
    else:
        cmd = 'usermod -G {0} {1}'.format(name, username)
    retcode = __salt__['cmd.retcode'](cmd, python_shell=False)
    return not retcode
```

As you can see, operating system commands are used. Which one depends on what operating system it is :)

Answer (score 3):

You could take 2 approaches:

1. Use the system() call to execute a shell command to do the work.
2. Directly modify the /etc/group file.  It should be fairly easy to locate the line that contains the group you wish to add to, and then append the user you want to add on the end (making sure to add a comma if there's already a group member).

Given the choice, I'd probably use the first option from the above.

EDIT: As @DevSolar pointed out in his comment, this answer is assuming that your system is using standard local authentication using passwd/shadow/group files in /etc.  If your system is NOT using local auth, then that's a completely different ballgame.

Comment: Note that group membership is not *necessarily* handled by `/etc/group`. (LDAP auth setups spring to mind.) Also, editing `/etc/group` requires root access, while e.g. `adduser` might be made available via `sudoers`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires **sudo**, however my app has no medium in which the user can add the password for **sudo**. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You could probably use libexpect to hand a password to sudo:

[link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libexpect)

Answer (score 1):

Jared Sutton's two options are valid, but I'd like to point out that you don't have to implement editing `/etc/group` yourself if you use an existing library.

I know of at least busybox, which has implemented this. There's a function defined in `libbb/update_passwd.c`

```
int update_passwd(const char *filename, // /etc/group
    const char *name,                   // username
    const char *new_passwd,             // nullptr
    const char *member)                 // groupname
```

If you do want to implement it yourself, then you can check out how their function works.